# JOIN UPDATE mysql, can't get it working

Tags: mysql, join

how do I use joins when updating in mysql? So far I have this...

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE items i JOIN accounts a SET i.shrapnel = i.shrapnel-1000, a.gender = a.? WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
$q -> execute(array($gender, $user['id']));
```

Am very new to this, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These work provided

- if the id field is in both `items` and `accounts` tables
- id is the same datatype in both tables

You can try

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE items i JOIN accounts a USING (id) SET i.shrapnel = i.shrapnel-1000, a.gender = a.? WHERE i.id = ? LIMIT 1");
$q -> execute(array($gender, $user['id']));
```

also

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE items i JOIN accounts a ON i.id = a.id SET i.shrapnel = i.shrapnel-1000, a.gender = a.? WHERE i.id = ? LIMIT 1");
$q -> execute(array($gender, $user['id']));
```

also

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE items i NATURAL JOIN accounts a SET i.shrapnel = i.shrapnel-1000, a.gender = a.? WHERE i.id = ? LIMIT 1");
$q -> execute(array($gender, $user['id']));
```

Comment: Ok will try this and thank you. Have not come across the `USING` syntax before, I guess this is when the primary keys are the same?

Comment: `USING (id)` is the same as `i.id = a.id`, provided the id field is in both tables and they are the same datatype. If it is then, `USING (id)` works.

Answer (score 0):

The id needed a table identifier.  I would also use "AS".

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE items AS i JOIN accounts AS a SET i.shrapnel = i.shrapnel-1000, a.gender = a.? WHERE a.id = ? LIMIT 1");
$q -> execute(array($gender, $user['id']));
```

Answer (score 0):

may you need a join **ON** something?:

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("
UPDATE 
  items i JOIN accounts a ON (i.commonField = a.commonField) 
SET 
  i.shrapnel = i.shrapnel-1000 , 
  a.gender = a.? 
WHERE 
  id = ? LIMIT 1");
$q -> execute(array($gender, $user['id']));
```

check: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html